# How to create a batch file using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to create a .bat file but with *PowerShell*. I want to create batch download like this:

```
$client.DownloadFile("http:///www.xyz.net/1.txt","C:\tmp\1.txt") 
$client.DownloadFile("http:///www.xyz.net/1.txt","C:\tmp\2.txt") 
$client.DownloadFile("http:///www.xyz.net/1.txt","C:\tmp\3.txt")
```

Is this possible to create a batch file to do this automatically?
Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.example.com/1.txt" -Outfile "C:\tmp\1.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for downloading the same file too several text files this should work

```
@ECHO off
set counter=1
:Start 
Powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.example.com/1.txt" -Outfile "C:\tmp\%counter%.txt"
set /a counter=1+%counter%
goto :Start
```

Comment: To not run endlessly you should put an `if %Counter% leq 3` in front of the goto.